# How do I utilize a config file with my Java program?

Tags: java

I'm trying to use a config file that holds a list of hosts/websites and a time frequency for each one.

ex.

```
google.com  15s 
yahoo.com   10s
```

My objective is to ping each website from the config file at every time period (15 secs).

Should I just read the config file and input the hosts/time into separate arrays?

Seems like there is a more efficient method...

Comment: What is the format of this config file? If it fits the format expected by [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), it might save you some implementation time using [`Properties.load()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29)

Comment: _Seems like there is a more efficient method_ You can do as @duffymo has shown below. A key lookup approach is swifter in use and more convenient than a multidimensional array. Did you have something else in mind? A properties file can also be used if there are no constraints for the config file itself.

Comment: There is no specific format for the config file. By key lookup, do you mean something like "url1 = google.com" in the config file and to retrieve that host I can use 'host1 = cfg.getProperty("url1")'?

I'm having trouble understanding how I pull all the hosts/times from the config file without knowing what is in the file (if that makes sense)...

Say there are 200 different hosts I need to ping in the config file...My program is to just start and run the config file and ping each one at their corresponding frequency on their own.

Comment: @pleasedeleteme Sorry, I'm new to this website and not sure if you get notified if I don't tag you.

Comment: I've added an answer explaining how you could use a properties file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick rundown of how to use a properties file.

You can create a file with the extension `.properties` (if under Windows make sure you have file extensions displayed) in the root of your project. The properties can be defined as pairs:

```
google.com=15
yahoo.com=10
```

In Java,

To get the ping time of a particular URL:

```
final String path = "config.properties";

Properties prop = new Properties();

int pingTimeGoogle = prop.load(new FileInputStream(path)).getProperty("google.com");
```

To cycle through the properties and get the whole list:

```
final String path = "config.properties";

Properties props = new Properties().load(new FileInputStream(path));
Enumeration e = props.propertyNames();

while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
    String key = (String) e.nextElement();
    System.out.println(key + "=" + props.getProperty(key));
}
```

Edit: And here's a handy way to transform properties into a `Map` (Properties implements the `Map` interface):

```
final String path = "config.properties";

Properties props = new Properties().load(new FileInputStream(path));

Map<String, Integer> pingUrlTimes = new HashMap<String, Integer>((Map) props);
```

Cycling through the `HashMap` can be done like this:

```
Iterator iterator = pingUrlTimes.keySet().iterator(); // Get Iterator

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) iterator.next();

    System.out.println(key + "=" +  pingUrlTimes.get(key) );
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. I learned something along the way. Hang around @duffymo as he knows his stuff ;)

Answer (score 2):

Why use two arrays when the two items are so intimately related?

I'd put them into a Map:

```
Map<String, Integer> pingUrlTimes = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
pingUrlTimes.put("google.com", 15);
pingUrlTimes.put("yahoo.com", 10);

int pingTime = pingUrlTimes.get("google.com");
```

Comment: Is there a way to populate the HashMap with the host/time values from the config file automatically? I believe I understand your answer here but what if I have 200 different URLs in the config?

Comment: @TT52 The way a `HashMap` works is that information is stored in key + value pairs. If you have 200 URLs you simply store them one by one as 200 pairs using the put method. When you need to ping a given URL you get it's ping time using the get method.

Comment: Read the file by looping over each line and do a "put" inside the loop.  How hard can it be?